# Best numerical integration method for this integral

Tags: integration

I have an integral as follows $$\int_0^\infty r^k \psi(r) dr \tag{1}$$ where $$\psi=e^{-ar-br^2-cr^3-dr^4}\tag{2}$$ 
I want to evaluate (1) numerically using a code (in Mathematica). Normal integration command returns error, so I'm going to write an algorithm myself, but I don't know what is the best method to do so. Any idea?

Comment: had you tried the command `NIntegrate`?

Comment: @Masacroso yeah however it returns error, so it seems that I have to modify it by specifying its method or write a new algorithm for the evaluation.

Comment: Mathematica generally doesn't works well with undefined parameters as $a,b,c,d$ and $k$

Comment: @Masacroso, Oh. I have defined in the beginning of my code, so they don't yield the error.

Comment: also for numerical computing consider the use of Julia instead of Mathematica, and some package like [this](https://github.com/JuliaMath/QuadGK.jl)

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks, but I have written the rest of my code in Mathematica and now should continue in it.

Comment: Any textbook about numerical analysis will introduce the idea of numerical integration. You may try different polynomials to interpolate the function, such as Hermite and Laguerre polynomials. The method may be like Gaussian quadrature within a finite interval.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable Thanks in fact I want to reproduce the results of a paper, so I have to use this polynomial

Comment: @Wisdom What do you mean by "*this polynomial*"?

Comment: @UnbelieveTable Sorry for mistype, I meant that I cannot use a polynomial because it  may reduce the accuracy. You know the authors used power-Pad approximant but I think it returns more error in integration step

Comment: @Wisdom Oh, but **any** numerical integration will definitely reduce the accuracy. The error is actually relatively small, and the fast decay of your function also helps with this.

Comment: @UnbelieveTable you think so? I will try that, many thank, so what is your suggested polynomial? as I said the authors used power-Pad approximant but I think it returns more error in integration step.